# Android studio - user login

Tags: android, kotlin

I have one problem on login user in library retrofit. 
I write an app in kotlin. When I clicked button login, make nothing. I don't know How to make a problem.

```
 buttonLogin.setOnClickListener{
                //val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java);
                //startActivity(intent);
                val email = editTextLogin.text.toString().trim();
                val password = editTextPassword.text.toString().trim();


                val call : retrofit2.Call<User> = RetrofitClient.create().login(email, password)
                call.enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<User>{
                    override fun onFailure(call: retrofit2.Call<User>?, t:Throwable?){

                    }

                    override fun onResponse(call:retrofit2.Call<User>?, response: Response<User>){


                        if(response.isSuccessful){

                            val user: User = response.body()!!

                            if(user.success.equals("true")){
                                Log.d("", "onResponse()");


                }
                                else {
                                    Log.d("", "onFail()");
                                }
                            }
                      }
                    })
```

> Blockquote

```
@FormUrlEncoded
        @POST("/login")
        fun login(@Field("email") email: String,
                  @Field("password") password: String)
                : retrofit2.Call<User>;
        //fun  login(@Query("login")login: String, @Query("password")password:String) : retrofit2.Call<User>
```

`

> Blockquote

```
class User {
    var success : String = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code execution might be redirecting to the onFailure part of retrofit code..

Put Log or Toast in onFailure section and run or debug!